# How to use Firebase Admin SDK with storage

Tags: java, firebase, firebase-storage, firebase-admin

I need to use Firebase Admin SDK to add files to storage. It seems problematic, and I cannot figure it out how to do it. Here is my initialization code:

```
FileInputStream serviceAccount = new FileInputStream("path/to/my/file.json");
FirebaseOptions options = new FirebaseOptions.Builder()
        .setCredentials(GoogleCredentials.fromStream(serviceAccount))
        .setDatabaseUrl("https://my-app.firebaseio.com")
        .setStorageBucket("gs://my-app.appspot.com")
        .build();

FirebaseApp.initializeApp(options);
```

Then, I get my bucket from this piece of code:

```
Bucket bucket = StorageClient.getInstance().bucket();
```

But every time, I am getting this error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.json.AbstractGoogleJsonClient$Builder.setBatchPath(Ljava/lang/String;)Lcom/google/api/client/googleapis/services/AbstractGoogleClient$Builder;
at com.google.api.services.storage.Storage$Builder.setBatchPath(Storage.java:9263)
at com.google.api.services.storage.Storage$Builder.<init>(Storage.java:9242)
at com.google.cloud.storage.spi.v1.HttpStorageRpc.<init>(HttpStorageRpc.java:94)
at com.google.cloud.storage.StorageOptions$DefaultStorageRpcFactory.create(StorageOptions.java:54)
at com.google.cloud.storage.StorageOptions$DefaultStorageRpcFactory.create(StorageOptions.java:48)
at com.google.cloud.ServiceOptions.getRpc(ServiceOptions.java:472)
at com.google.cloud.storage.StorageOptions.getStorageRpcV1(StorageOptions.java:122)
at com.google.cloud.storage.StorageImpl.<init>(StorageImpl.java:99)
at com.google.cloud.storage.StorageOptions$DefaultStorageFactory.create(StorageOptions.java:44)
at com.google.cloud.storage.StorageOptions$DefaultStorageFactory.create(StorageOptions.java:38)
at com.google.cloud.ServiceOptions.getService(ServiceOptions.java:459)
at com.google.firebase.cloud.StorageClient.getInstance(StorageClient.java:62)
at management.AdminService.<init>(AdminService.java:29)
at Main.main(Main.java:17)
```

What is wrong? :D Google Admin SDK tutorial with storage seems enigmatic.

Comment: This error is either because you have a newer version of google-cloud-storage or an older version of google-api-client in your classpath. Assuming you're on the latest Admin SDK, try syncing up your dependencies (and transitive dependencies) to what's declared in https://github.com/firebase/firebase-admin-java/blob/v5.8.0/pom.xml

Comment: Ok, thank You very much Hiranya, Your comment was very useful and now it is working!!

Answer (score 2):

When you call setStorageBucket(), you should just pass the name of the bucket, not the gs URL:

```
.setStorageBucket("my-app.appspot.com")
```

However, the error message I get if I use `gs://` is different from yours.  I'm using version 5.8.0 of the SDK.

You're right, the docs are not very clear.  I'll raise an issue internally with team.